# ANDROID Listview alignment within linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to align a listview in middle of 2 views, I tried the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/white">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No data"
            android:id="@+id/empty_state"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_stock_listView"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:layout_above="@+id/add"
            android:layout_below="@+id/empty_state">
    </ListView>

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/add">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="70dp"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:clickable="true"
                      android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                       android:src="@drawable/plus_small_blue"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/mm_blue"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dp"
              android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result in preview is:

[image: preview]

But when the list have less items than screen height, the listview dont get alligned below the "no data" textview, the listview down and gets on top of "add", like the following:

[image: preview 2]

**DETAIL:** When the list have data I set the "no data" textview visibility to GONE.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try using match_parent for the listview's height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @CChi suggested i changed the listview height to match_parent, and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need textview for Nodata and ListView in Linerlayout.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

need LinearLayout for TextVeiw (Nodata) and ListView

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:text="No data" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_stock_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/add"
        android:layout_below="@+id/empty_state"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/plus_small_blue" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textColor="@color/mm_blue"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
      </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```